# Calling Proj2PageB.aspx page from Proj1PageA.aspx of another Project in same Solution

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-projects

I am stuck in a condition where i have a single solution consisting of multiple projects.

E.x. -> In one solution i've Project 1 which has Proj1PageA.aspx and i've another Project 2 which has Proj2PageB.aspx. 
Now i've a multiple conditions where based on UserType the user will be response.redirected("") to the related project in the solution for its given page.

Please suggest me how to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: why would you do that? How do you maintain the session state and cookies etc?

Comment: that is a good question. do you have any idea about the same or if anybody else can help me out with this too ?

Comment: it's not "about the same", you can simply do a redirect to the absolute url on your other project, when you deployed your application to the web server, they don't know about what's outside their own project, a solution is just a logical group of your projects together.

Comment: but it generates error of irrelevant path to the form. I've the following structure :

Solution

       Project1 (Project)

             LoginForm (Folder)

                      Proj1PageA.aspx (Form)

       Project2 (Project)

             BookingForms (Folder)

                      Proj2PageB.aspx (Form)

       Project3 (Project)

             AgentsForms (Folder)

                      Proj3PageC.aspx (Form)

Now in above if i use Response.Redirect("~/Project2/BookingForms/Proj2PageB.aspx") it given me an error that page does not exists.

Comment: yes because you are using a relative path, not an absolute path

Comment: you have to read my previous comment, because i posted it hoping that you will understand what i am trying to explain to you and make you understand how to solve your problem, i'm not providing you a copy&paste answer because your question is not detailed enough